# Why is fillStyle undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Working on an angular 2 project that draws into an html 5 canvas.  The main functionality is that the users mouse position is drawn onto the screen and slowly disappears (gets covered over by semi transparent rectangles)

Right now when I run the script I get this error:

> Cannot set property 'fillStyle' of undefined

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
interface mouseInterface {
  previousX: number;
  previousY: number;
}

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CanvasService {

  context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  canvas: any = null;

  init(canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.canvas.style = 'border:solid 1px red;'
    this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.fadeOut();

  }

  fadeOut() {
    let ctx  = this.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,.2)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    setTimeout(this.fadeOut, 100);
  }

  draw(data) {
    //does drawing behavior based on mouse position
  }

}
```

Comment: To clarify, `fillStyle` is not undefined, `ctx` is.

Comment: Are you sure that the init method is called before the fadeOut one?

Answer (score 0):

With the code I can see here your init() won't be called.

1. Name the method: ngOnInit()
2. add implements OnInit to: export class CanvasService implements OnInit
3. Add import Statement for OnInit: import{Injectable, OnInit}
4. Check if your service is listed in the providers list in app.module.ts